# How to link a submit button based off a label from a list?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to have the submit button to redirect the user to another page based off their selection on the drop down menu.

here's my HTML.

```
<div class="select-box" onchange="val()" id="dropdown">
  <div class="selected">
  what are we doing today? </div>
  <div class="options-container">

    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="studying" name="category" value="studying" />
      <label for="film">Studying</label>
    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="wo" name="category" value="wo" />
      <label for="science">Working Out</label>
    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="party" name="category" value="party" />
      <label for="music">Party</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="submit" style="font-size: 20px;">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the event when you select a radio option (onchange="val(event)"), then assign the event.target.value into a variable.

```js
let selectedValue;

const val = (e) => {
  selectedValue = e.target.value;
  console.log(selectedValue)
}

const onSubmit = () => {
  window.location.replace(`www.google.com/${selectedValue}`);
}
```

```html
<div class="select-box" onchange="val(event)" id="dropdown">
</div>

<button onclick="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```